# How to actually unsubscribe from the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange Newsletter?

Tags: support

I've been getting the *Worldbuilding Stack Exchange Newsletter* through email every week. I don't think I deliberately subscribed to it, and don't particularly want it. I finally made the effort to try to unsubscribe from it today.

Down at the bottom of the email is this notice saying that I subscribed to the community digest (no, I don't think I did) and to follow a link to unsubscribe:

[image]

When I follow that link, it says I'm *not* subscribed to the community digest:
[image]

I tried following the "Edit email settings" link instead. None of the settings there seem to be particularly relevant to this particular piece of email.

How do I *actually* unsubscribe from this Fine newsletter?

Comment: Have you set all of them to OFF, into the email settings?

Comment: @L.Dutch No. The settings on the "email settings" page mostly appear to affect all SE sites, not just worldbuilding. There are a few emails from other SE sites which I am interested in getting.

Comment: Well, +1 for advertising that we even háve a newsletter!  Who knew!?!?